# Probability Theory: Proving that $P(A \mid B) \ge 1 - \frac{\mathbb P(A')}{\mathbb P(B)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Prove inequality:

$\mathbb P(A \mid B) \ge 1- \frac{\mathbb P(A')}{\mathbb P(B)}$

I expanded the conditional probability on the left side of the inequality through the formula:

$\mathbb P(A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb P(A\cdot\ B)}{\mathbb P(B)}$

Then on the right side I brought everything to a common denominator and got:

$1 - \frac{\mathbb P(A')}{\mathbb P(B)} = \frac{\mathbb P(B)- \mathbb P(A')}{\mathbb P(B)}$

After the transformations, I get the following expression and remove the common denominator:

$\mathbb P(A\cdot\ B) \ge \mathbb P(B)- \mathbb P(A')$

But I don’t know what to do next and how to prove the original simplified expression. Tell me please

Comment: To obtain $\ge$, type `$\ge$`.

Comment: Thank you! I can't find this one, so then wrote incorrectly

Comment: Substitute $P(A')=1-P(A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy observe that

$$\mathbb{P}[AB]\ge \mathbb{P}[B]-\mathbb{P}[A']$$

can be rewritten in

$$\mathbb{P}[AB]\ge \mathbb{P}[B]-1+\mathbb{P}[A]$$

that is also

$$\mathbb{P}[A]+\mathbb{P}[B]-\mathbb{P}[AB]\le 1$$

or

$$\mathbb{P}[A\cup B]\le 1$$

which completes the proof

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank you!